# How to cancel submit on AjaxForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm working with a jQuery plugin (ajax form), I try to implement something like this:

```
$("#MyFormID").ajaxForm({
    dataType: "json",
    resetForm: true,
    beforeSubmit: function() {
       //validateData returns boolean
       if (validateData()) {
          // continue submit
       } else {
          //cancel submit
       }
    },
    success: function(json) {
        //show success notification     
    }
});
```

is there a way to stop the ajax from submiting the form?
on beeforesubmit function maybe?

Comment: It's simple, don't run the function ?

Comment: Don't use it. If you use something why may you need to stop it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `return false;` in `beforeSubmit` function to prevent form submission.

Source: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

Answer (score 6):

Call `xhr.abort()` in `beforeSend` callback.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined`.  However, `return false;` worked fine.

Comment: @Keven, you have to define the beforeSend as follows: beforeSend: function(xhr) {...}. You probably forgot that when you tested it. xhr.abort() worked for me while "return false" didn't, so thank you Dmitry.

Comment: return false didn't worked for me but xhr.abort() worked fine